# Query output is not displaying on the page

Tags: php, html, mysql, sql

I have the following query/output that does not show anything/work. All of the column table names are correct. I have php error checking on and it is not throwing any errors.

This is the code that is not outputting anything.

```
$total_members_query = $con->prepare("SELECT COUNT(id)FROM users WHERE `group` IN (2,3,4,5)")
    or die ("Total Members query failed: %s\n".($total_members_query->error));
    $total_members_query->execute();
    $total_members_query->bind_result($total_members);
    $numrows_members = $total_members_query->num_rows();
//  $numrows_members = mysqli_num_rows($total_members_query);
    if($numrows_members > 0){

    while($members_row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($total_members_query)){
        //$members_total = $members_row['id'];
?>
                            <div class="member_summary_statistics">
                                <div class="member_summary_category_title">League Statistics</div>
        <div id="member_summary_member_count">Members in your league: <?php echo $total_members; } } ?></div>
```

Here is more code. A little above and below it.

```
<div class="member_summary_user_birthdays">
                            <div class="member_summary_category_title">Today&#39;s Birthdays</div>
                        </div>
<?php
$total_members_query = $con->prepare("SELECT COUNT(id)FROM users WHERE `group` IN (2,3,4,5)")
        or die ("Total Members query failed: %s\n".($total_members_query->error));
        $total_members_query->execute();
        $total_members_query->bind_result($total_members);
        $numrows_members = $total_members_query->num_rows();
    //  $numrows_members = mysqli_num_rows($total_members_query);
        if($numrows_members > 0){

        while($members_row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($total_members_query)){
            //$members_total = $members_row['id'];
?>
                            <div class="member_summary_statistics">
                                <div class="member_summary_category_title">League Statistics</div>
        <div id="member_summary_member_count">Members in your league: <?php echo $total_members; } } ?></div>
                                    <div id="member_summary_newest_member">Welcome our newest member - <?php echo $member_username;?>!</div>
```

Everything in this line after the & sign shows up in a gray color rather than black and blue in my file manager.

```
Today&#39;s Birthdays</div>
```

Then my two titles do not show up after the Birthday text..

```
class="member_summary_category_title">League Statistics</div>
        <div id="member_summary_member_count">Members in your league:
```

I didn't know if any of this factored to what is going on because I have looked at this over and over again and cannot figure anything out.

I'd appreciate any help.

Comment: I have also tried taking out this `y&#39;s` from the Birthday line. Still my div's or php output do not show up. They do not show up in the page source either.

Answer (score 0):

Looks like you're missing a space between `COUNT(id)` and `FROM` in your prepare statement.

Edit:
You also need to buffer the result set, see [Mysqli documentation](http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli-stmt.num-rows.php):

```
$total_members_query->execute();
$total_members_query->bind_result($total_members);
$total_members_query->store_result();
$numrows_members = $total_members_query->num_rows;
```

Edit 2:
Taking a closer look at your statement, I realize that your query will always return one row (since COUNT will be at least 0), why you might want to take an approach like this instead:

```
<?php
$total_members_query = $con->prepare("SELECT COUNT(id) as countId FROM users WHERE `group` IN (2,3,4,5)")
    or die ("Total Members query failed: \n" . ($total_members_query->error));
    $total_members_query->execute();
    $total_members_query->bind_result($total_members);
    $total_members_query->fetch();
    if($total_members > 0){
    ?>
    HTML-code...
```

Comment: Thanks, didn't help though. My titles and this output are still not showing.